# Joining Elements from a List of Tuples in Python

Tags: python, list, tuples, concatenation

I have a list of tuples:

```
MyList = [('abc', 'def'), ('ghi', 'jkl'), ('mno', 'pqr')]
```

I want to do something like this:

```
s0 = '\n'.join(MyList[0]) # get all tuple elements at index 0
s1 = '\n'.join(MyList[1]) # get all tuple elements at index 1
```

Comment: This code does not work.

Comment: Works for me... What's your expected output?

Comment: It does not throw an error, but the results are wrong. I need to combine all Nth elements of each tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the list you can try something like:

```
MyList = [('abc', 'def'), ('ghi', 'jkl'), ('mno', 'pqr')]

# Need to iterate over the list elements and pick the targeted tuple elem.
s0 = '\n'.join(item[0] for item in MyList) # 'abc\nghi\nmno'
s1 = '\n'.join(item[1] for item in MyList) # 'def\njkl\npqr'
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're selecting the first tuple not the first value of each tuple.

```
>>> s0 = '\n'.join(l[0] for l in MyList)
>>> s0
'abc\nghi\nmno'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l0 = []
l1 = []
for (v1, v2) in MyList:
    l0.append(v1)
    l1.append(v2)
s0 = '\n'.join(l0)
s1 = '\n'.join(l1)
```